# How to change flutter project name and id?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Is it possible to change flutter project name and organisation ?
I want to change only the project's name and organisation id without recreating the whole project with `flutter create <project name> --organisation <organisation-id>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dart package like [rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) where you can change the bundle id and package name for different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

name can be changed from `pubspec.yaml` file and `bundle id` is something that you can change from specific platform wise. for android in app -> `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the project name, simply change it in all these files.

`1.build.gradle (app)`

`2.AndroidManifest.xml`

`3.MainActivity.java`

Answer (score 0):

#### Finally I solved the problem by using the Dart Package Rename.

It worked. Here is the link
[rename package](https://pub.dev/rename)